# passing data from php to javascript for hybrid apps

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

i'm building a cross platform mobile application using intel xdk and i need to retrieve data from php running on the server into my javascript...... this is my js code

```
var meRequest;
meRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
meRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(meRequest.readyState==4)
    {
        alert("request sent");
        alert((meRequest.responseText));
    }
}

meRequest.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/my_queries_1.php",true);
meRequest.send();
```

and this is my php code:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(500);
exit;
?>
```

this works when i run them both from localhost, i.e both scripts are on the server but i can't use this since for the app, the js has to be embedded in the mobile application and the php script remaining on the server... but if i run the javascript file outside local host get a null responseText.
how do i go about this please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need cross domain request and I think something like this should work for you:

```
// (1)
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

var xhr = new XHR();

// (2) cross domain request
xhr.open('GET', 'http://anywhere.com/request', true);

xhr.onload = function() {
  alert( this.responseText );
}

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert( 'error ' + this.status );
}

xhr.send();
```

Server side should also allow such requests via generating special response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

Comment: hi... i'm getting an error 0 alert... could you shed more light on the server side... the third line of your code,i'm assuming it indicates which domain should be allowed to make cross domain requests... could that be replaced with '%' so it allows access from all devices??.. Thank you

Comment: A returned resource may have one Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, with the following syntax:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> | *
The origin parameter specifies a URI that may access the resource.  The browser must enforce this.  For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.

Comment: More info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: still receiving error 0...  and no alert at all from xhr.onload...  how do i allow such requests from the server? .. do i include that in my php script??  tried that... not working... sorry if i sound likean idiot

Comment: No worries Lukman. Here is a php headers documentation: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php  and here is how you send header  header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit; , but it should be on top of your php file and after your php scripts prints out the json or xml data put die or exit function. replace Location: http://www.example.com/ with your header information.

Comment: Same error 0 still.. this is my php code `<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo json_encode(500);
exit;
?>
`